# Unix batch rename folders (underscores to spaces)

Tags: unix

I have a collection of folders, and I would like to replace all underscores in the folder names with spaces.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure?  Spaces in file names are likely to cause some hassles.  Unix supports them fine - not all tools written for Unix do.

Comment: To the closers: this is an appropriate question for SO - it is asking how to write a shell script (a program) to do a particular task.  If you were closing it as a duplicate of another question, you'd get more sympathy from me.

Comment: I actually found this on Google looking for the opposite task (spaces to underscores) - this was useful for me!

Answer (score 3):

(bash) This will find all folders in or beneath current directory with an underscore in the name and rename them as you mention:

```
for d in $(find . -name '*_*' -type d) ; do
    new=$(echo $d | sed -e 's/_/ /g')
    mv $d $new
done
```

Comment: I enclosed the $d and $new in quotes and it did the trick.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like

```
#> ls -l | grep '^d' | awk '{oldname = $9 ; gsub(/_/, " " ,$9);  print "mv " oldname " "  $9 }' > temp.script
#> chmod 744 temp.script
#> ./temp.script
```

Test it first of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Does your system have a `rename` command that does what you need?  On some systems, it exists and can use some species of regular expression to make the changes.  I use a version which uses Perl regular expressions (a Perl script, in other words):

```
find . -type f -name '*_*' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/_+/ /g'
```

On the other hand, the standard version on Linux tends to be rather feeble by comparison (and wouldn't do what you need).

Note that if you want to rename directories too, then do them before renaming any files, or after renaming all the files.  Doing them mixed up will mean that your renaming runs into problems with accessing file names that were in one directory but the directory has been renamed since the file name was generated.  Even using `-depth` as an option to `find` is not guaranteed to be safe.